# Split view controller menu in w/o split view controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I am making an iPad app, and am wondering it is possible to get the pop down menu from a UINavigationBar without having to go through the trouble of a split view controller. Is this possible? Tell me if I'm not being specific enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that without much trouble, but you just have to write the code. Just display a UIPopoverController from that UIBarButtonItem on your navBar.

The steps:

- Create a UIViewController which manages a table view (or whatever else you want) as your menu view controller.
- Add a UIBarButtonItem to your nav bar or toolbar.
- Create an IBAction to called something like touchedMenuButton.
- Connect that action to that UIBarButtonItem.
- In that method, alloc/init that view controller.
- alloc/init a UIPopoverController with that view controller.
- present that popover from the UIBarButton item
- Success!